# Es6 how to check if an item exists in an array built from a nodeList using includes()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, nodelist

I cant seem to figure this one out I am trying to check if an input is inlcuded in an array of nodes. No matter what I try it seems to return false. I'm thinking it must be something simple that I'm missing.

Here is what I have

```
const error = document.getElementsByClassName('has-form-error')
let focusedInputNodeList = error[0].childNodes
let focusedInput = Array.from(focusedInputNodeList)
```

This is to check for the most immediate form error. I then want to check the return if it is an input, textarea, or select.

the above code returns the array to console from my html

```
(6) [text, label, text, div.form-error, input#first_name, text]
```

Then I try

```
console.log(focusedInput.includes('input')) //returns false
```

I figured maybe it was due to the #first_name so I tried using

```
console.log(focusedInput.includes('text')) //returns false
```

and

```
console.log(focusedInput.includes('#text')) //returns false
```

None of these attempts seemed to work. My goal is to eventually have something that looks like

```
if (focusedInput.includes('input')) {
    focusedInput[4].focus() //even better if I could find a way to select focusedInput.input.focus()  
}
if (focusedInput.includes('textarea')) {
    focusedInput[5].focus() // even better if I could find a way to select focusedInput.textarea.focus()
}
```

Comment: .includes doesn't work for objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your array `focusedInput` contains elements and not strings. In the code below I get an additional array of the element types, as strings, and from that you can find what you want.

The other thing I did was to use `.children` to get all of the non-text elements to reduce what is in the array.

```js
const error = document.querySelector('.has-form-error');
let focusedInputNodeList = error.children;
let focusedInput = Array.from(focusedInputNodeList);
let nodeTypes = focusedInput.map(el=>el.localName);
console.log(focusedInput);
console.log(nodeTypes.indexOf('label'));
console.log(nodeTypes.indexOf('input'));
```

```html
<div class="has-form-error">
  <label>Click me</label>
  <div class="form-error">Error</div><input id="first_name" />
</div>
```

*UPDATE*

In a comment you said: "even better if I could find a way to select focusedInput.input.focus()"

So why not do this:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.has-form-error input');
if (input) {
  input.focus();
}
```

```html
<div class="has-form-error">
  <label>Click me</label>
  <div class="form-error">Error</div><input id="first_name" />
</div>
```

Comment: this is great too! but remember that indexOf only returns the first instance, so in the example there are 3 `text` nodes, and that may cause an issue.

Comment: In my example there are NO text nodes. `.children` vs `. childNodes`

Comment: Thank you for this. It's helped me figure quite a bit out, and the second solution is a much more elegant way of accomplishing what I was attempting.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just check for includes like that, since it's not an array of strings `['text', 'input', 'etc']`. It's an array of node objects, and the name you're looking for is a property of that node, which you can find like `focusedInput[5].localName` (or `.tagName` or `.nodeName`). 
So, like:

```
focusedInput.forEach(item => {
    if (item.localName === 'input') {
        item.focus()
    }
})
```